# css text fade out effect on a background image

Tags: css, text, fadeout

What I want to do is fade out on some text in a div with background image.

Normal linear gradient solution isn't gonna work here because the background image is not consistent. So using single color linear gradient would be awful.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Would like to make the image fade in hover or in other conditions?

Comment: @d_z90 fade the image wouldn't help the text's fade effect I suppose.

Comment: I replied you with a possible solution. If it doesn't work for you, could you paste the relevant part of your code? Just to be able to give you a better reply.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [transitions](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) for css? This could be an example of your code:

```
.background  {
    background-color: #333;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-out;
    transition: all 3s ease-out;
}

.background:hover {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: You can apply the same effect to the div of your text